# How do signals interact with sequence points?

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals, volatile

The C89 standard states:

```
At sequence points volatile objects are stable in the sense that previous
evaluations are complete and subsequent evaluations have not yet occurred.
```

The C89 standard also states:

```
When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a
signal, only the values of objects as of the previous sequence point may be
relied on.
```

These requirements leave me confused, because I can't imagine how they would
actually be implemented. I only have a rudimentary understanding of x86-64
assembler, but here's what is running through my head. Let's say that we have
a volatile struct, and it's many kilobytes large. If you copy an existing
struct into this volatile struct in C, then the resulting machine code might
be very large. Now, let's say that this large amount of machine code is
executing, and some shell on the system executes the "kill" command on the
process, causing the raising of some signal. My understanding (or rather my
guess) is that the process would be interrupted in mid-copy, causing the
requirement on volatile to be broken, and causing the struct be malformed from
the perspective of any signal handler.

Obviously things don't actually work like this, but then how do they actually
work? For the sake of argument feel free to assume that the platform is x86-64
or x86 Linux, Windows, OS X, or some other common UNIX.

Answer (score 3):

> At sequence points volatile objects are stable in the sense that previous
>   evaluations are complete and subsequent evaluations have not yet occurred.

This wouldn't be violated, since the interruption is not a sequence point. This rule only describes what happens "at sequence points". If we are interrupted after sequence point A and before sequence point B completes, we aren't "at" sequence point A or sequence point B.

> When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a
>   signal, only the values of objects as of the previous sequence point may be
>   relied on.

This wouldn't be violated. If we are interrupted between sequence points A and B, say in mid copy, all the changes made at sequence point A can be relied on. They're done.

Being able to relying on a previous modification doesn't mean that you won't see any effects of a subsequent modification. Values are stable until some future bit of code can modify them.

So the obvious implementation doesn't violate either of the requirements.

Comment: Let's say that the volatile structure is set to value Alpha at sequence ponint A, and then to value Beta at B. Now let's say that a signal handler triggers between A and B, in mid-copy. The structure will have mostly values from Alpha, but it will be partly populated with values from Beta, and so the volatile structure's value *cannot* be relied upon, and so the obvious implementation doesn't meet the standard's requiremnts. That's still my current understanding.

Comment: @patrick-rutkowski Of course you can't rely on something to have a previous value once you set it to a new value. That's not what "relied upon" means! It just means that you can never see a value previous to that. It doesn't mean that a subsequent operation won't change the value. You can "rely on" a store operation if there is no way you can see the result prior to that store and are guaranteed to see either the result of that store or something that happened after it.