# On signals in C programming

Tags: c, signals, volatile

I am reading the C11 ISO standard and I am having a hard time understanding a clause dealing with signals.

Specifically clause 5 under section 5.1.2.3 describing a programs execution on the abstract machine:

> 5. When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the values of objects that are neither lock-free atomic objects nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t are unspecified, as is the state of the floating-point environment. The value of any object modified by the handler that is neither a lock-free atomic object nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t becomes indeterminate when the handler exits, as does the state of the floating-point environment if it is modified by the handler and not restored to its original state.

Does this means that all data objects, such as variables on the stack, the heap, and the .data segment in the program will have an indeterminate state after a signal is handled or does it  mean any object actually access by the signal handler is indeterminate.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975051

Comment: Are you asking if the values go back to normal when the signal handler returns?

Comment: No not exactly. The clause to me sound like the value of any variable could have changes when the signal handler returns even if the signal handler does not directly access (I am assuming with the question that the signal handler does not longjmp and completely modify the stack)

Comment: In my understanding, it means that the values of some objects are unspecified **in a signal handler** .

Comment: @ZenoofElea "The clause to me sounds like the value of any variable could have changed..." . The section **5.2.3 Signals and interrupts** prohibits that behaviour, if my understanding is correct: _Functions shall be implemented such that they may be interrupted at any time by a signal, or may be called by a signal handler, or both, with no alteration to earlier, but still active, invocations' control flow (after the interruption), function return values, or **objects with automatic storage duration**._

Comment: It's very clear what that text say: "The value of any object __modified by the handler__ ... becomes indeterminate ... as does the state of the floating-point environment __if it is modified__ by the handler". The standard writers only can do that much; then cannot keep repeating again and again: but only if they're modified, but only if they're modified.

Answer (score 0):

This only refers to variables that are used both in the signal handler and outside of it.

Any other variables (not used in handler or used only in handler) are safe (determinate).

For example lets say you have a global variable that is used inside a signal handler and in another function, than that variable must be either volatile non-lock atomic variable or volatile sig_atomic_t.

Any variables from other variable types shared like this might indeed be indeterminate. For example if it was changed by the handler the old value might still be used in the function we stopped in the middle, however it is possible the new value will be used (in non atomic maybe a sort of combination might be used - which might be complete nonsense), as said it will be indeterminate.

Btw - int and pointer types should be atomic, see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Types.html however I do not recommend to assume that,you should use atomic when needed. The var must be volatile as it is used mid-function, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183083/8901188.

Comment: *int and pointer types can be assumed as atomic, see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Types.html*  The "In practice, you can assume that int is atomic. You can also assume that pointer types are atomic" of that link is **very** wrong.  **Never** assume any type that is not **explicitly** atomic is such a variable, unless your standard for writing code is "I hope this works".  You can ask Boeing how well that standard works...